# DB2 SQL Return One Row from Left Joined Table Based on Custom Weighting

Tags: sql, db2, left-join

I have two tables, 'INVOICES' contains invoice information and 'CSEML' contains customer email addresses. The email address type (field EMLTP) could be designated as 'AP' (Accounts Payable), 'PO' (Purchasing), or blank (default). Each customer could have 3 email addresses in CSEML (one for each designation). I'd like to be able to do this within the query: join the invoice table to the email table and pull a maximum of one email address per invoice - the AP address if it is defined, otherwise the PO address if it is defined, otherwise the default address if defined, otherwise null.

CSEML is structured like this

```
CUSTNO,EMLTP,EMAIL
000989367,PO,po@example.com
000254785,PO,po@example3.com
000989367,,default@example.com
000112354,,default@example2.com
000989367,AP,ap@example.com
000254785,,default@example3.com
```

Right now I have the following query

```
SELECT I.INVNO, I.CUSTNO, E.EMAIL 
FROM INVOICES I 
LEFT JOIN CSEML E ON I.CUSTNO = E.CUSTNO
WHERE I.INVNO = '10124'
```

Which returns something like this when there are all 3 addresses defined:

```
10124    000989367    po@example.com
10124    000989367    default@example.com
10124    000989367    ap@example.com
```

How can I assign a weight to the different email 'types' so that I'm only getting the most preferred address available?

**Working Code based on accepted answer**

```
SELECT INVNO, CUSTNO, EMAIL
FROM(
    SELECT I.INVNO, I.CUSTNO, E.EMAIL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.INVNO
        ORDER BY
            CASE WHEN E.EMLTP = 'AP' THEN 0
                 WHEN E.EMLTP = 'PO' THEN 1
                 ELSE 2 END) rn 
    FROM INVOICES I 
    LEFT JOIN CSEML E ON I.CUSTNO = E.CUSTNO
    WHERE I.INVNO = '10124'
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `ROW_NUMBER` here with a `CASE` expression to order/prioritize the email addresses of each invoice:

```
SELECT INVNO, CUSTNO, EMAIL
FROM
(
    SELECT I.INVNO, I.CUSTNO, E.EMAIL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.INVNO
        ORDER BY
            CASE WHEN E.EMAIL LIKE 'ap@%' THEN 0
                 WHEN E.EMAIL LIKE 'po@%' THEN 1
                 ELSE 2 END) rn
    FROM INVOICES I 
    LEFT JOIN CSEML E
        ON I.CUSTNO = E.CUSTNO
    WHERE I.INVNO = '10124'
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Tim, thank you this worked for me. I did change the case statements to look at the EMLTP field for constant values rather than at the email address as those wouldn't always follow the simplistic email examples that I used.  Code edits will be added to my original question.

Comment: @Dano Yes, I was going to ask you about those email addresses as well, but I gave what I thought was the best answer based on your sample data given.

Answer (score 1):

You should get your preferred email first, then join to `INVOICE` or whatever later. Probably the best way is in a CTE or just a view.  E.g.

```
CREATE VIEW CUSTOMER_PREFERED_EMAIL AS
SELECT CUSTNO
,      COALESCE((MAX(CASE WHEN EMLTP = 'AP' THEN EMAIL END))
               ,(MAX(CASE WHEN EMLTP = 'PO' THEN EMAIL END))
               ,(MAX(CASE WHEN EMLTP = ''   THEN EMAIL END))
               ) AS PREFERED_EMAIL
FROM   CSEML E
GROUP BY
        CUSTNO
```

which given the following table and data

```
CREATE TABLE CSEML(CUSTNO int, EMLTP CHAR(2), EMAIL VARCHAR(32));
INSERT INTO  CSEML VALUES 
 (000989367,'PO','po@example.com'     )
,(000254785,'PO','po@example3.com'    )
,(000989367,'','default@example.com'  )
,(000112354,'','default@example2.com' )
,(000989367,'AP','ap@example.com'     )
,(000254785,'','default@example3.com' )
;
```

will return

```
 CUSTNO PREFERED_EMAIL
 ------ --------------------
 989367 ap@example.com
 112354 default@example2.com
 254785 po@example3.com
```

and you can then join that view to whatever you need